# How to get the Wireless SSID using Visual Basic using .net framework 4.5.2

Tags: vb.net, wifi

I have been searching for a while and I can't seem to figure out how to get the SSID of a wireless network. tbh I just need some form of unique identifier so that I detect when I connect to a network that I have already connected to. I'm coding in Visual Basic and using the .net Framework 4.5.2. Thanks

-R

Comment: do you just to display the current connected wifi's name in your VB program?

Comment: Yes. Just some way to turn it into a string or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK to get the current connected wifi's name try this, 
 
Go to `NuGet` `Package Manager` > `Manage NuGet Packages For Solution`.
click on Browse and search for `managedwifi`
Install the package (There should only be one)

Once thats done, Follow this example I have made for you.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Text
Imports NativeWifi

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
''THIS WILL DISPLAY THE CONNECTED WIFI'S NAME ON START UP.
Dim wlan = New WlanClient()
Dim connectedSsids As Collection(Of [String]) = New Collection(Of String)()

For Each wlanInterface As WlanClient.WlanInterface In wlan.Interfaces
    Dim ssid As Wlan.Dot11Ssid = wlanInterface.CurrentConnection.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid
    connectedSsids.Add(New [String](Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(ssid.SSID, 0, CInt(ssid.SSIDLength))))

    For Each item As String In connectedSsids
        Label1.Text = item ''CHANGE THE LABEL TO A TEXTBOX OR WHERE EVER YOU WANT TO DISPLAY YOUR CONNECTED WIFI'S NAME.

Next

Next
''CONTINUE ON FROM HERE.
End Sub

End Class
```

If you have any issues, let me know and I will do my best to reply to you quickly.
 
Happy Coding!

Comment: No problem at all, Please mark the question as correct so it can help the next person :)